# NullReferenceException-> Hammock.WindowsPhone.dll! Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.GzipHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, hammock

I want to use Twitter in my app and i am using Twitter using Hammock Windows DLL,SO when i create the rest client like this

```
private void GetTwitterToken()
{
    var credentials = new OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.RequestToken,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = MyTwitter.ConsumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret = MyTwitter.ConsumerSecret,
        Version = MyTwitter.OAuthVersion,
        CallbackUrl = MyTwitter.CallbackUri
    };

    /*
    var client = new RestClient
    {
        Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth",
        Credentials = credentials,
        HasElevatedPermissions = true
    };
    */

    var client = new RestClient
    {
        Authority = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth",
        Credentials = credentials,
        HasElevatedPermissions = true,
        SilverlightAcceptEncodingHeader = "gzip",
        DecompressionMethods = DecompressionMethods.GZip
    };

    var request = new RestRequest
    {
        Path = "/request_token"
    };
    client.BeginRequest(request, new RestCallback(TwitterRequestTokenCompleted));
}

private void TwitterRequestTokenCompleted(RestRequest request, RestResponse response, object userstate)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Twitter Request Token Completed");

    _oAuthToken = GetQueryParameter(response.Content, "oauth_token");
    _oAuthTokenSecret = GetQueryParameter(response.Content, "oauth_token_secret");
    var authorizeUrl = MyTwitter.AuthorizeUri + "?oauth_token=" + _oAuthToken;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_oAuthToken) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(_oAuthTokenSecret))
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("error calling twitter"));
        return;
    }

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => browserControl.Navigate(new Uri(authorizeUrl)));
}
```

I am getting error as NullReferenceException->  Hammock.WindowsPhone.dll!

> Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.GzipHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream() + 0x1c bytes

and in the stack, I am getting the error as

> at Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.GzipHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
>
> at Hammock.Web.WebQuery.GetAsyncResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
> at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b*_8(Object state2)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
>
> at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

What could be the problem?

Comment: Well the exception isn't in the code you've *given*... please show the full stack trace of the exception, and where it occurs in your code.

Comment: at Hammock.Silverlight.Compat.GzipHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at Hammock.Web.WebQuery.GetAsyncResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8

(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback 

callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Comment: Please edit that into your question, along with your code *using* the API. This may well just be a bug in Hammock of course.

Comment: Well you still haven't shown your code using the API...

Comment: No, but if you could come up with a short but *complete* program - ideally as a console app, if you can - it'll make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: sorry for wierd way of asking jon.

Answer (score 0):

There was reference problem,that was causing the problem,it was fixed,Thanks for your support jon

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem. Please tell me, What was the fix?

Comment: Problem was that it was referring to some old Hammock .dll file in debug,Once i removed and made a clean reference,there was no issue after that